# Remove specific XML tag from string via PHP

Tags: php, xml, regex, replace, preg-replace

I need to remove only the specific tag `</licenses>` from an XML file saved to a variable.

I've tried this, but I'm not getting the expected output:

```
<?php

  print preg_replace("</licenses>", "", "</licenses>");

?>
```

Returns:

```
<>
```

And surprisingly, the following removes the contents of all tags:

```
<?php

  print preg_replace("<>", "", "</licenses>");

?>
```

All I can think is that I'm somehow hitting a regex pattern or something.
How can I do this?

Comment: It is because `<` and `>` are [used as the delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Only what is inside them, "`/licenses`", will be replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use regex delimiter in the first argument of `preg_replace` which is a regex:

```
 echo preg_replace("#</licenses>#", "", "</licenses>");
```

This will return an empty string as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it.

```
print preg_replace("/<\/licenses>/", "", "</licenses>");
```

Comment: `<` and `>` are not special characters and do not need to be escaped.